# Why this regex ignores the rest of matches?

Tags: php, regex, replace

I want to match all occurrences for **pony** word, except in these situations:

- [url=**pony**.com]**pony**[/url]
- [url]**pony**.com[/url]

In synthesis, the matches should be:

> **pony** en **pony** [url=pony.com]pony[/url], también tengo que **pony** [url=pony.com]pony[url], y no olvidar a [url]pony.com[/url]

To accomplish the goal, I have created this regex:

```
(?!\[url[^\]]*?\])(pony)(?![^\[]*?\[\/url\])
```

However, for some some reason, the matches are the following:

> **pony** en **pony** [url=pony.com]pony[/url], también tengo que **pony** [url=**pony**.com]**pony**[url], y no olvidar a [url]pony.com[/url]

Why is happening this? My idea at first place it to find the correct occurrences, and then, replace them using php.

Comment: If you want to replace them all, use preg_replace() rather than finding them in one function and replacing them in another

Comment: To do that you must match what you want to avoid: `/thatIdontwant|pony/`

Comment: @MarkBaker, to do so I think that I need a regex, that at this point, is the reason of this question

Comment: javascript or PHP - which is it?

Comment: @jfriend00, apologies, Javascript tag removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It matches the following conditions because you are missing a forward slash.

> **pony** en **pony** [url=pony.com]pony[/url], también tengo que **pony** [url=**pony**.com]**pony**[url], y no olvidar a [url]pony.com[/url]

```
                                                                   ^ missing '/'
```

Add the slash and it works, see [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/qA7hM3)

Comment: Hahaha Oh my God! that typo! Thank you so much!

Comment: /I/love/forward/slash/my/favorite/technique ;) +1

Comment: However, the first negative lookahead is useless, and the pattern will fail if the `[url]` tag contains an other BBcode tag.